# Why ng-if function repeating itself?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am passing a boolean function in ngIf attribute instead of boolean condition in html template file. But that boolean function is repeating itself based on amount of data in variable messages. If messages have 2 objects than value of ctr in console is increasing from 1 to 69 approx instead of just 1 or 2. What could be the reason for it and how to avoid it while passing function in ngIf attribute?

**HTML**

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index; trackBy:trackByMsgId">
      <ion-badge *ngIf="isNewDate(i)" color="primary" class="ion-margin">{{message.time | date: 'longDate'}}</ion-badge>
</ion-row>
```

**TS**

```
let ctr = 0;
isNewDate(i) {
    this.ctr += 1;
    console.log('ctr: ', this.ctr);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The function is executed for each element every time angular has decided the template needs to be rendered depending on your change detection strategy. That could be **a lot**. Relevant - [never use function calls in Angular template expressions](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)

Comment: This is the reason why you don't bind to functions but rather variables.

Comment: @Ploppy - also why you should use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` everywhere. But it's understandably difficult to do this in codebases that weren't built that way and instead just relied on "angular magic". Still encouraged to find the simple components and convert them one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `isNewDate()` function will be called every time the Angular runs `ChangeDetection` based on the [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy#changedetectionstrategy), Because Angular cannot predict whether the return value of `isNewDate()` function has changed. So, it needs to execute the function every time change detection runs.

Updating `DOM` is a part of `ChangeDetection` and `ngFor` directive updated the `DOM`, and will run the Angular `ChangeDetection`. So if you have an array with `length` 4 and `ChangeDetection` runs 4 times 4 each item, your function will be called 16 times, but component variable `ctr` will be restarted per each item. You can see a sample here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkh6a8?file=src/app/app.component.html). So, thanks for @Adam helpful comment and according to the [mentioned article](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496):

> While function calls in Angular templates are super convenient and
> technically valid, they may cause serious performance issues.

**And because of that you should never use function calls in Angular template expressions. It's not a best practice.**

The solution to avoid function calls:

1. Use `pipes`
2. Manually calculate the values and update some `Variables` in `app.component.ts` and using them in template (`app.component.html`).

Comment: So what's the solution? Pipes?

Comment: Yes, Using `Pipe` or manually calculates are two solutions here.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks @bravemaster; I mean calculating the values in `component.ts` & updating some variables based on and binding those variables to `template`